# rails link_to not works when navigated to any entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I cannot navigate or post when there is a parameter on the url (when navigated to any entity)

`<a href="/xxx">xxx</a>` only works when i am at a url like

`http://localhost:3000/xxx`

but when i am at a url that has a entity parameter like

`http://localhost:3000/xxx/12`

non of the `<a\>` tags work and non of remote form posts work

When I attach to mouse click on Chrome, I saw that on a url like `http://localhost:3000/xxx` the jquery function below returns `undefined` (the situation which navigation works without problem), but when on a url like `http://localhost:3000/xxx/12` function returns **jQuery.fn.init[0]**

The function (jquery excerpt) is this

```
if ( !( eventHandle = elemData.handle ) ) {
        eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {

            // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
            // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
            return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
                jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Show routes and controller code

Comment: Need your routes code